# Genesis.json in private (geth) network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis

My genesis.json

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 9731,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"Ethash": {
  "period": 15,
  "epoch": 30000
}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x5d5769ad",
"gasLimit": "0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF",
"difficulty": "0x1",
"alloc": {
"0x02404f2fd8fb1323efe14603968ffc9ee21c4f4f": {
  "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

After upping the geth I am getting below message

```
config="{ChainID: 9731 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: <nil> Petersburg: <nil> Istanbul: <nil> Engine: ethash}"
```

1. It is showing DAO nil and DAOsupport false (is it a problem to call the smart contract). How to make DAOsupport as true.

2.after deployment the smart contract the functionalities are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest Solidity compilers depend on features introduced in Constantinople and Petersburg. Please enable it for your own network and use below JSON file.

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 9731,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0,
"ethash": {}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x5d5cdc87",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x47b760",
"difficulty": "0x80000",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
  "balance": "0x1"
}
},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably aren't mining any Blocks.
So the smart contract transactions don't get mined.

Comment: I started mining with miner.start() command.